# How to check if docker port 2375 is listening and working

Tags: docker

In the MacOS, docker desktop was installed, and it is running.

I have an application that complains about

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to http://127.0.0.1:2375 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Then I use command to check if port 2375 is open and listening

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN
```

Seem I could not find port 2375

Then, I add this json to Docker engine from Docker desktop

```
  "hosts": [
    "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
    "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"
  ]
```

Then a complete json in the Engine, it looks like

```
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  },
  "hosts": [
    "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
    "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"
  ]
}
```

After I restart docker daemon, when I ran command

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN
```

I still could not see docker port 2375.

My question is, I could not see port 2375 is listening from docker, is it normal? How to check if port 2375 is working well? Because my application complains failed to connect 127.0.0.1:2375.

Comment: Hy Joe this link might be helpful for you
https://gist.github.com/styblope/dc55e0ad2a9848f2cc3307d4819d819f

Comment: Follow the above link, I didn't find how to work with MacOS.

Comment: In general, unencrypted TCP access to the Docker socket is a major security issue, and you should _never_ assume Docker is available this way and you should _never_ try to enable it.  The standard Docker SDKs know how to access Docker through a Unix socket and this is normally the right approach.  If you're trying to deal with a third-party tool, you might file a bug report that their tool is unusable without enabling a root-exploit security vulnerability.